# How come 2d array indexing doesn't conflict

Tags: arrays, memory, multidimensional-array, data-structures

So I am studying **2D arrays** and found that since they are **contiguously** stored just like **1D array** How come the indexing doesn't conflict there?

Here is a pictorial representation of my 2D arrray

[image: pictorial representation of 2d array]

and here I have tried to mimic how it is represented in memory.

[image: memory structure of 2d array]

Now suppose that the **arr[0][0] is at x0001** memory location then when I try to access arr[0][3] which is clearly an out of bound index, how does it shows me the error.
I am using the following formula for indexing -
`(n*m+c)+B` for indexing where

- n = current row
- m = Total columns
- c = current column
- B = size of datatype(lets suppose B = 1 for simplicity)

Now for **arr[0][3]** and **arr[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeKfN.png)][0]** the output of the formula `(n*m+c)+B` is the same(**3**) and if we add that value to the **initial pointer(x0001)** then we will get the same memory address(**x0001+3=x0004**) then how come the statement arr[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeKfN.png)][0] returns **13**(value at x0004) but arr[0][3] returns index out of bound error.

---

## Assumptions

Since I don't have the clear idea how memory in 2D arrays actually work I assumed the following things

1. The formula `(n*m+c)+B` is practically used instead of just theoretically understanding how 2D array works.
2. The address is contiguous and counted from the initial cell i.e. **& of arr[0][0]** => (**x0001**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the described behaviour, the formula appears to be:

```
assert c >= 0 && c < m or out_of_bounds
assert n >= 0 && n < t or out_of_bounds
return s+n*b*m+c*b
```

Assuming

```
s = start
n = current row
m = total columns
t = total rows
c = current column
b = size of datatype
```

Comment: So, even though there is more than just direct indexing happening to retrieve the value at a particular location, still it counts as O(1)???????

Comment: O(1) + O(1) + O(1) = O(1)

Comment: @Mahi it's O(1) because the running time and space remain the same regardless of sizes. The operation already did multiplications and additions as well as retrieving a value, but these are not looked at for big O notation.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what you mean by "conflict".  It is true that the formula produces the same result for different indices *if the indicies are allowed to be out of bounds*; if index values are limited to legal ones, there is no conflict.

Different languages handle this differently (ignoring the ones that don't represent a 2D array as a contiguous section of memory).  One approach  would be to ignore the issue, following the philosophy "garbage in, garbage out".  Another would be to check the indices explicitly before even attempting to locate the cell in question.